# Inheritance and the prototype chain

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I have been reading through Mozilla Developer Network lately on JavaScript inheritance model. I am highly confused on one point. Here's the code from MDN:

```
function Graph() {
  this.vertices = [];
  this.edges = [];
}
Graph.prototype = {
  addVertex: function(v) {
  this.vertices.push(v);
}
};
var g = new Graph();
console.log(g.hasOwnProperty('vertices'));// true
console.log(g.hasOwnProperty('addVertex'));// false
console.log(g.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('addVertex'));// true
```

What I don't understand is that why does `g.hasOwnProperty('addVertex')` yields false since addVertex is a property of g although it's defined in Graph's prototype but still it is part of Graph.

Also I had one more question: that if some object inherits from g (or so to say Graph) will it inherit only addVertex (those defined in Prototype of function) or it will inherit all three properties of graph namely vertices, edges and addVertex.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, since you spend time learning something new, why don't you step right up to ES6 classes? It's much more readable and has the same performance.

Comment: Yeah i am looking forward to them but i right now i have heard that they are just sort of syntatical sugar and JS still remains prototype based language

Comment: Yup, but that's no reason not to use it :) But all in due time. Learn all you can and decide what works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `hasOwnProperty` specifically says it return false on `inherited` properties

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

> The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the
>   object has the specified property as own (not inherited) property.

As for your second question - it depends on exactly **how** you have an object inherit from `Graph`. In the ES5 way, I would do this:

```
var InheritedFromGraph = function() {
  Graph.call(this);
}

InheritedFromGraph.prototype = Graph.prototype;
```

and then, yes, `InheritedGraph` will get the properties `verticies` and `edge` that `Graph` defined in it's constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but u mean to say that addVertex has been inherited but i clearly defined it in Graph.prototype and if it is inherited then whose member is addVertex is like vertices and edges are properties of Graph ?

Comment: A property on `Graph.prototype` is **not the same** as a property on `Graph`

Comment: And what's the difference between the two?

Comment: If you've got any questions, read the spec: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/ search for `HasOwnProperty` and then search for `GetownProperty` (which `HasOwnProperty` implements.

Comment: The difference between the two is that when you call `Graph.call(this)` inside the `InheritedFromGraph` constructor - then the `Graph` constructor is executed in the context of `InheritedFromGraph` and, thus, `verticies` and `edges` are assigned directly on the object created using `new InheritedFromGraph` and are not `inherited` (via  a prototype, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

> why does g.hasOwnProperty('addVertex') yields false

That is the way `hasOwnProperty` works. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

> The `hasOwnProperty()` method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as own (**not inherited**) property.

So `hasOwnProperty`does not traverse the prototype chain when do its checks.

You can use [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator to check property in prototype chain.